# Create child directories from parent directory

Tags: bash

A parent directory has many directories, for example:

```
$ cd parent
$ ls
ALA_31_C   ALA_31_D   ALA_31_G  ALA_31_L
```

I want to create the same name directory within each child directory, something like this:

```
$ cd  parent
$ ls
ALA_31_C   ALA_31_D   ALA_31_G  ALA_31_L

$ cd ALA_31_C
$ ls
ALA_31_C
```

Similarly, I need to create it for all remaining directories: `ALA_31_D`, `ALA_31_G` and `ALA_31_L` from the parent directory.

Comment: Why you want a directory with the same name as its parent? Seems an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Maybe there is a better solution

Answer (score 3):

A simple Bourne shell script will do it:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
  
for dir_name in */ ; do
    echo "$dir_name"
    mkdir "$dir_name/$dir_name"
done
```

Loop through only the directories (`*/`), and for each directory, make a child with the same name as the parent (`mkdir "$dir_name/$dir_name"`).

This only works for one level - it is not recursive - which is probably what you want anyway.

For more examples, see [How do I loop through only directories in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/86722/97255)

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a little late to the game here, but Occam had it right (the simplest solution...):

```
mkdir -p ~/folder/{child1,child2,child3,child4}
```

This gives the results:

```
user@computer:~/folder/$ ls -a
.  ..  child1 child2 child3 child4
```

The folders are not nested, but all folders are children of the parent!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).